# Adding a participant label when dialling in conference (Twilio)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-python

```
conference.participants.create(from_=caller_id, to=to_number, label='customer')
```

This piece of code is returning an error

> TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'

I read from https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource that label is one of the parameters of participant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I upgraded the Python Twilio helper library, it worked for me:

Worked: Successfully installed twilio-6.45.3

Didn't Work: Found existing installation: twilio 6.39.0

`pip install --upgrade twilio`

Looks to be added here:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/main/CHANGES.md#2020-06-24-version-6430

Comment: I see, I was using twilio==6.35.2.