# Twilio TwiML Set Participant Label

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Twilio [Conference Participant Labels](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/conference-participant-labels)
[image: Twilio]

I'm trying make an outbound call, but before that I want my client to be added into a conference

```cs
VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse();
var dial = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Dial();
var conf = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Conference("blah_blah_conf", muted: true);
conf.Append(new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Parameter("label", "firstparticipant"));
conf.Append(new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Parameter("name", "firstparticipant"));
response.Append(conf);
response.Append(dial);
```

Generates this `TwiML`

```xml
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference muted="true">
            <Parameter name="label" value="firstparticipant"></Parameter>
            <Parameter name="name" value="firstparticipant"></Parameter>
                blah_blah_conf
        </Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

But later when I query list of participants, I cannot see participant-labels.

Could some one please point out what I'm doing wrong

> Note: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041544/), but I want to do this via TwiML

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks like:

```
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Conference, Dial, VoiceResponse

response = VoiceResponse()
dial = Dial()
dial.conference('moderated-conference-room', start_conference_on_enter=False, participant_label="memow")
response.append(dial)

print(response)
```

Comment: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/twiml/VoiceResponse.js

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/main/src/Twilio/TwiML/Voice/Conference.cs

I didn't find `participant-label` in c-sharp and neither in node as well, please correct me if I'm looking at wrong place. Thanks for responding

Comment: Good question, open an issue on the respective repo and see what they say, not sure looking here, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/twiml/VoiceResponse.js.
Issue: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues, Issue: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues.

Comment: Alright thanks Alan, I'm waiting for twilio support ticket response